# Python Error: class RequestsCookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar, collections.MutableMapping): - in file cookies.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10

when I run the program I suddenly get an error (on many files). I think the error refers to another file located in Python, `cookies.py`.

> class RequestsCookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar,
> collections.MutableMapping):

See this print screen:

[image]

HERE IS THE FULL ERROR:

```
>>> 
*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Carte\BB\17 - Site Leadership\alte\Ionel Balauta\Aryeht\Task 1 - Traduce tot site-ul\Doar Google Web\Andreea\Meditatii\Sedinta 9 (2022) (EMAIL)\BEBE-PARSING-Python (fara redenumire 2).py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\Castel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\Castel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .cookies import RequestsCookieJar, cookiejar_from_dict
  File "C:\Users\Castel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 172, in <module>
    class RequestsCookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar, collections.MutableMapping):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
>>>
```

Comment: Could you please post full error log and preferably not an image but copy and paste it here as text and mark it as code?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: yes, I copy the entire error on description of the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

THIS WILL SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM:

Copy/Install this on CMD:

`pip install uplink`

See [here](https://pypi.org/project/uplink/) the description: